# Intersection of two submanifolds with dimension condition

Tags: general-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, intersection-theory, submanifold

Consider a manifold of dimension $n$, we have two submanifolds $A$ and $B$, with dimension $n_1$ and $n_2$ that satisfies $n_1+n_2=n$. Can we conclude they only intersect at finite points (or isolated points)? How does one prove this?

Motivation: The reason that I asked this question is I was looking at the definition of the intersection number. In [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_theory) it says the following

[image]

So I wonder why we have **they intersect generically at isolated points when the dimension adds up to the total dimension**.

Comment: You forgot to assume that the submanifolds are smooth. Then, indeed, generic intersections (properly defined) will be discrete because generic intersections are transversal. My favorite reference for this staff is the book by Guillemin and Pollack.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thanks! That makes a lot of sense when we require the intersection to be transversal!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't true even if you restrict yourself to $\mathbb{R}^n$.
For example, consider these two 2-dimensional planes in $\mathbb{R^4}$:
$$A = \{(x,y,0,0) \mid x,y \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
$$B = \{(x,0,z,0) \mid x,z \in \mathbb{R}\}$$
Then, $A\cap B$ is the line $\{(x,0,0,0)\mid x \in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: You are right so prob I need to set some other restrictions. I will edit the problem.

Comment: This is a great example. Particularly as generically two planes will always intersect in a line.